# java search-getting an integer value from a string preparedstatement

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have this Java code, and I want to be able to search for `YEAR` (which is an `int`) into a `TextField` and show a table. How do I implement it in the `prepareStatement`? Do I need to parse?

```
try
    {
        connection = DBConnect.getConnection();


        //int filmyear = Integer.parseInt(txtSearch.getText());

        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT filmtitle, filmyear, filmgenre, companyname FROM production, film, company  WHERE (LOWER(filmtitle) like LOWER (?) OR "
        + "LOWER (filmgenre) like LOWER (?) OR filmyear = ?)and production.companyid = company.companyid AND production.filmid = film.filmid");

        statement.setString(1, "%" +txtSearch.getText()+"%");
        statement.setString(2, "%" +txtSearch.getText()+"%");
    //  statement.setInt(3, +txtSearch.getText());


        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(); 
         table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As you can see i tried to create another `statement.setInt(3, +txtSearch.getText());`, which I suspect is wrong.

`filmtitle`, `filmgenre`, and `filmyear` are in the same table.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: if you have problems converting string to integer you can cast type in your query. eg `select '2003'::int` will give you integer 2003, so if you change `OR filmyear = ?` to `OR filmyear = '?'::int` you have same anf can pass java strings safely. but gogically this `like LOWER (?) OR filmyear = ?` should be `like LOWER ('?') OR filmyear = ?`

Comment: @VaoTsun won't it give sql exception when type casting if passed value is string..

Comment: @udaybhaskar `select '2003'::int` returns integer `2003`

Comment: yeah i get an error when i do that  The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:56)

Comment: You can answer your own Question.That might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already tried this. It should be working fine.

```
int filmyear = Integer.parseInt(txtSearch.getText());
```

then

```
statement.setInt(3, filmyear);
```

Comment: sadly doesnt work..when i try searching for 2000 it gives 2004 values

Answer (score 0):

i think you can search filmyear as a string it can gives you a proper result.

statement.setString(3,+txtSearch.getText());